# d3js approach to specifying a line in domain coordinates

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I wrote this javascript function to draw lines in to d3js container with given scalings so that the coordinates are domain specific.

```
function drawline(svg, x1, y1, x2, y2, xScale, yScale) {
    svg.append("line")
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .attr("x1", xScale(x1))
        .attr("y1", yScale(y1))
        .attr("x2", xScale(x2))
        .attr("y2", yScale(y2));
}
```

I suspect that this is a fairly clumsy approach that misses a much simpler d3js shorthand.
Is there a more canonical d3js or indeed Javascript way of implementing this?

Comment: whst part makes it clumsy? I mean your opinion

Comment: (1) passing the container as an argument to a fn. (2) is it more javascript friendly to write this as a method of the container? (3) is there already  a feature in d3js that does this?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code.  **But** you might be passing them needlessly, most `d3` code just relys on the container and scale variables being in the parent scope outside the function:  `svg = d3.select('body')...; xScale = d3.scale.linear(); yScale = d3.scale.linear(); function drawline(x1, y1, x2, y2) { svg.append...; }`